# Trying to append an array of jQuery elements into DOM

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
function rearrangeBySort(allTasksPerSection) {
  if (allTasksPerSection.attr("class").match("task-incomplete")) {
    debugger;
    $(".task.task-incomplete").replaceWith(allTasksPerSection)
  } else {
    $(".task.hide.tasks-hidden").replaceWith(allTasksPerSection)
  }
};
```

and allTasksPerSection is a jquery proxy array:

```
[<div class=​"task task-incomplete">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"task task-incomplete">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"task task-incomplete">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"task task-incomplete">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"task task-incomplete">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"task task-incomplete">​…​</div>​]
```

I want to use replaceWith here to replace a black of HTML with my array of divs called allTasksPerSection. What do I do? Apparently replaceWith doesn't work with appending jquery elements to the DOM? What do I do if allTasksPerSection is an array of divs?

Comment: Check with hasClass() `allTasksPerSection.hasClass("task-incomplete")`

Comment: The issue is because you're attempting to call `attr()` on an array, not a jQuery object. What behaviour are you trying to create?

Comment: Have you tried using `.append()`? Does the debugger hit?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think it is a jQuery object.

Comment: `[]` is an array, `{}` is an object. Also, you didn't escape each element in the array. That'll be an issue, too.

Comment: But the result of allTasksPerSection.attr("class") === "task task-incomplete"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function rearrangeBySort(allTasksPerSection) {
  $(".task.task-incomplete").empty();
  allTasksPerSection.each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("task-incomplete")) {
      debugger;
      $(".task.task-incomplete").append($(this));
    } else {
      $(".task.hide.tasks-hidden").append($(this));
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: He wants logic depending on if _all_ tasks are incomplete from what I understand.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think the solution here is to iterate the array and then append it to div whatever condition is met and that's what OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the elements with a jQuery selection:

```
var tasks = $(allTasksPerSection);
```

This will cause jQuery to treat it as a selection set, you can now execute selectors against it:

```
tasks.find(".task-incomplete"); // all incompete tasks
tasks.find(".task-incomplete").length === tasks.length; // all tasks have the class
```